# BigQuery Regex to extract string between two substrings

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

From this example string:

```
{&q;somerandomtext&q;:{&q;Product&q;:{&q;TileID&q;:0,&q;Stockcode&q;:1234,&q;variant&q;:&q;genomics&q;,&q;available&q;:0"}
```

I'm trying to extract the Stockcode only.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, r".*,&q;Stockcode&q;:/([^/$]*)\,&q;.*", r"\1")
```

So the result should be

> 1234

however my Regex still returns the entire contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `regexp_extract(col, r"&q;Stockcode&q;:([^/$]*?),&q;.*")`

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks for your help, this did the trick. Much appreciated @mikhail-berlyant